# TeamCity FxCop Selecting MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset has no effect

Tags: fxcop, teamcity-8.0, fxcopcmd

I have added a Build Step in TeamCity 8.0.6 (build 27767) to execute FxCop against a specific c# project assembly.

When running FxCop from within VS 2013 with the MinimumRecommendedRules set I get no errors or warnings (I fixed them all).

Now I want to wire this up in TeamCity. To limit the rules I am specifying a command line property as follows:

```
/ruleSet:=MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset  /rulesetdirectory:'FxCop\Rule Sets'
```

(The rulesetdirectory parameter points to a location in my source tree which contains the full contents of the standard Rule Sets folder)

However this does not have the desired behaviour, the FULL rule set is run and I get an error as follows:

> FxCop warning: Keyword=CA0063 Kind=Engine Type=Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.FxCopException * Failed to load rule set file 'MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset' or one of its dependent rule set files.

And this is the TeamCity generated command line:

> [17:32:29]Starting: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe" /forceoutput /ignoregeneratedcode /ruleSet:=MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset "/rulesetdirectory:'FxCop\Rule Sets'" /f:dal\bin\release\MyDAL.dll /out:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\fxcop-output-1891867450083417003\fxcop-result.xml

Can anyone spot what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out so hopefully this is helpful to someone else.

the /ruleSet: parameter needed to have the full (relative or absolute) path to the ruleset file as follows:

```
/ruleSet:"=%teamcity.build.workingDir%\FxCop\RuleSets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset"
```

(Note: the double quotes are to handle the possibility that the teamcity.build.workingDir might contain spaces)

Secondly, the second command line parameter /rulesetdirectory: is no longer necessary. I suspect this second parameter does not actually work.

Please also note, my working command line parameter here points at my MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset file in my source code. It could just as easily have been copied into the standard Rule Sets folder under "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets".

And finally, as my projects are all VS 2013 and TeamCity only recognises up as far as v10 I also set "Specifiy installation root" to "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop" explicitly to ensure that the latest version of FxCop was being used and would not choke on .Net 4.5 code. (Note: I have VS 2013 installed on the build server because of C++ project build requirements, I'm not happy about this but it turned out to be convenient for me in dealing with the FxCop set up. There are other ways to put the FxCop stuff on your build server without installing VS 2013)